# Doubts with routing inside tabs app and leaving

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, routes, ionic4

I'm doing an app of data of a game, with data of characters, skills, etc, with the tab template of Ionic 4. After some searchs, I found a way to show a page inside tab UI without the tabsbar, but I found some problems and doubts about it.

Following this demo (https://github.com/servrox/demo-ionic-tab-routing), in my tab with news I created a function which redirects to a page with the full new, but when the user leaves clicking on another tab inside the tabsbar, if the user come back to the news tab he will enter in the new page instead of the page with all the news.

This is my code right now:

Function from noticias.page.ts

```
abrirNoticia(prueba) {

    console.log(this.noticias[prueba].n);


    let id = this.noticias[prueba].n;

    let navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
      queryParams: {
        noticia: id
      }
    };

    this.navC.navigateForward("/tabs/noticias/noticia", navigationExtras);

  }
```

I tried with this but it doesn't work.

```
ionViewDidLeave(){

    console.log("Back");

    this.navC.pop();

  }
```